# Managing the Network from a linux machine

Tags: linux, networking, nmap

I am using Linux at my work, and i am kind of a sys admin / IT support, (not exactly my title but i do this kind of things since there is no one else). There are mostly Windows user in my organization and some linux users, we have linux servers (mostly ubuntu server) and windows server and of course firewalls and printers etc'. A regular small company of 30 people.

I am looking for a bunch of tools for linux (xubuntu 11.10) to install on my computer to help me manage the network.

Something like nmap but easier and faster to use with some more capabilities:

a. mapping the network, (open ports, coumputers names etc') in a nice visual way

b. access shares on computers with easy access to windows shares without me needing to type in "mount -t cifs \10.0.0.10\share ./joshua-comp -o username=dsadasd" all the time.

10x.

Comment: a) might be Zenmap, part of nmap; b) on GNOME or KDE one could just enter `smb://10.0.0.10/share`; on Xfce/Xubuntu you can install just the needed parts of GNOME (specifically Nautilus instead of the default file manager).

Answer (score 1):

Nagios isn't bad (I JUST installed it recently and haven't looked at most of it yet, but so far it's not bad). Intermapper is very good, but its very expensive. Spiceworks is decent if you can deal with the ads. Might not be too bad for only 30ish machines.

If you have several shares you map to consistently you can put them in the fstab file under /etc to make them mount each time you boot the machine. May keep you from entering the command each time for more of the common ones.